# Identifying which JS functions and CSS is used for a component in a web page

Tags: javascript, ember.js, refactoring, html-content-extraction

I have been asked to re-factor a website containing 50 html page. Site is using EmberJS and using plain html. I am not aware of EmberJS. Since code is spread across multiple JavaScript, CSS, HTML, and handlebar files. Its little difficult to understand.

I wonder if there is a easy way to understand the code. Is there any tool\plugin\extension which when inspecting an element will tell me what HTML/CSS/JavaScript code its using?

If not what is the best way to understand and modify the code with-in limited time.

Comment: First, I'm sorry you have to go through this.  Second, I have to say, the Chrome `Network` tab in the developer console is awesome for just this.  Refresh and watch the sources load.  You can then filter down to css, scripts, things loaded from ajax, filter by search bar, etc...  Really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Ember is an application framework that can be used to build single-page applications.  Are you sure the site is an Ember app?  Either way, the best tool for inspecting and debugging an Ember application is the Ember Inspector: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Yes its an EmberJs application, When i said 50 web pages, I meant code is using lot of placeholders & though its a SPA, based of route different pages get loaded. I did consider using this extension but in my company we cannot install chrome & therefore cannot use any of its extension.

Comment: If you, as a developer, are not "allowed" to install Chrome, then you're not really in a software development organization.  I'd recommend a new job.  I can't imagine doing this work without proper tools.